# Wordpress Page, change DIV Display Value when Clicking Link

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm attempting to display a login form when the user clicks a line "Login" on my page.  As a user clicks the link, the intention is to use JQuery to change the CSS style of the div class from "display: none;" to "display: block;".

I've tested this in the W3 Schools code editor and it seemed to work fine.  However, when I tried applying this to my wordpress site, it does not work.

I've modified the code in within the page's head tags, the content area, and of course the css file.  Here's the snippets of code from each file:

**style.css**

```
#breadcrumbs-login { position: relative; float: right; color: #fff; padding-top: 9px; }

#breadcrumbs-login a { color: #fff; }

#floating-login { position: absolute; background-color: #999; color: #000; z-index: 10; right: 10px; padding: 5px; border: 1px; }
```

**includes/breadcrumbps.php**

```
<div id="breadcrumbs-login"> 
        <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                           $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
                           echo 'Welcome ' . $current_user->user_firstname;
                   } else { ?>
                           <a href="#" id="floating-login-trigger">Login</a> |
                           <div id="floating-login" class="login_onclick" style="display:none;">
                           <?php echo do_shortcode('[bbp-login]'); ?>
                           </div>
                  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

and of course the within the head tags in **header.php**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#floating-login-trigger").click(function(){
                $("login_onclick").css({
                    "display": "block;"
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Also, if anyone knows of an easier way to do this (such as plugins designed for this type of task), I'm open to suggestions as I haven't found much in my own searches.

Comment: Put your code in a separate file and enqueue it using[`wp_enqueue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/), making it dependent on `jQuery`. Also if you want to have AJAX login form, feel free to check out a tutorial I made on my site: [clicky](http://madebydenis.com/adding-login-ajax-form-to-your-wordpress/)

Comment: Thanks Denis, but I'm not entirely sure how to do that.  I'm still fairly new to wordpress.  Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so in your `functions.php` you need to find where your scripts are enqueued. Chances are you already have some script where you can put your code in. But if not you can add it yourself:

```
<?php 

define( 'TEMPPATH', get_template_directory_uri() );
define( 'THEME_VERSION', '1.0.0' ); // or whatever your version is

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'yourtheme_theme_setup' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'yourtheme_theme_setup' ) ) {
    function yourtheme_theme_setup() {
        //actions go here
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'yourtheme_frontend_scripts' );
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'yourtheme_frontend_scripts' ) ) {
    function yourtheme_frontend_scripts() {

        wp_enqueue_script( 'yourcode_js', TEMPPATH.'/js/custom_code.js', array( 'jquery' ), THEME_VERSION, true );

    }
}
```

Now you have [enqueued your script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) that depends on `jQuery`. So remove the scripts from your header, especially `jQuery` because it's already loaded by WordPress on default, and your script will depend on it explicitly.

In the newly file you put in `js/` folder called `custom_code.js` with your code in it

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    'use strict';

    $('#floating-login-trigger').on('click', function(){
        $('.login_onclick').css('display', 'block');
    });

});
```

This should do it. On your page you should have `custom_code.js` visible when you inspect your page. Just remember to remove the code and `jQuery` from the header. You don't need that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: OK, I tried each step as you mentioned, but unfortunately it's still not working as intended.  I removed the original code from the header, created the custom_code.js file and posted the code, and added the code into the functions.php.

Comment: Do you have a link to the page so that I can see if the file is enqueued?

Comment: Sure, here's that link.  Thanks for taking a look.

http://www.renewedpulse.com/forum

Comment: I had an error in the code. Missing `.`. Change `$('login_onclick').css('display', 'block');` with `$('.login_onclick').css('display', 'block');` and it will work.

Comment: That works!  Thanks Denis.  Only thing I want to fix now is that I had to copy the custom_code.js file into the parent js folder.  How do I point it to the child theme and not the parent?

Comment: Well just enqueue it in your child theme, should work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this syntax,

```
$("#floating-login-trigger").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();

    var loginDiv = $("login_onclick");

    if(loginDiv.css('display') == 'none'){
        loginDiv.css('display', 'block')
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks Samir, I tried copying your version into the header, but still, it's not working.  Any other tips?